# Win32 custom control with child controls

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

I've created a custom container control (owner drawn and more) which contains child controls.
Unfortunately, these child controls are never updated (they do not receive WM_PAINT)

Do you have any idea where can be the issue?
creation of window

```
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
             WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT  , 
             _T("PopupControl"),
             _T("Popup Control"),
              WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CLIPCHILDREN|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,
             100,100,420,220  ,
             NULL,
             NULL, GetModuleHandle(0), NULL
           );
```

creation of child control

```
CreateWindowEx(0, L"button", TEXT("Type here"),
WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 
200,15,100,20, 
hwnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(0), NULL);
```

Thanks and regards,

Comment: Show style, styleEx, and class style for container and children.

Comment: This should not compile, GetModuleHandle() returns the wrong type of handle.  Don't mess with STRICT.

Comment: What do you suggest instead of GetModuleHandle() ?

Comment: @AP: The parameter is optional, you can just pass NULL there.

Answer (score 0):

Add `WS_CLIPCHILDREN|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` styles to container control.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunatly the issue is still there.

Comment: You create "button"? Why do you think, they don't receive WM_PAINT? You override class procedure???

Comment: Using Spy++ I can see that they receive messages but not the WM_PAINT.

Comment: In fact, there are many possible causes. For example, you may validate them before WM_PAINT... Without full code can't say more